# tweak Kubernetes Job behaviour, retain kubernetes pod logs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

How to retain Kubernetes failed Pods associated with a Job

I have tried with annotations available at the Job level.

```
restartPolicy
backOffLimit
TTLAfterFinished
activeDeadlineSeconds

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: sample-job
  labels:
    app: "sample-job"
    chart: "sample-chart"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "sample-job"
    spec:
      backOffLimit: 5
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
        - name: sample-job-container
          image: <image>
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

I want to know the configuration which I can apply on the Job file to retain pods forever even when Job fails after specified retries for debugging purpose

Comment: Could you specify your question? According to documentation job pods are not deleted after job fails.

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup):

> When a Job completes, no more Pods are created, but the Pods are [usually](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy) not deleted either. Keeping them around allows you to still view the logs of completed pods to check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic output. The job object also remains after it is completed so that you can view its status. It is up to the user to delete old jobs after noting their status. Delete the job with kubectl (e.g. kubectl delete jobs/pi or kubectl delete -f ./job.yaml). When you delete the job using kubectl, all the pods it created are deleted too.

And:

> If your job has `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"`, keep in mind that your Pod running the Job will be terminated once the job backoff limit has been reached. This can make debugging the Job's executable more difficult. We suggest setting `restartPolicy = "Never"` when debugging the Job or using a logging system to ensure output from failed Jobs is not lost inadvertently.

In summary:

- Pods are usual kept around when the Job is terminated (regardless of success or failure)
- If you find your Pods are removed, it may be because `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` and it has reached `.spec.backoffLimit`. Try setting `restartPolicy = "Never"` instead.

Comment: This has not been my experience. Am working with CJs now and `kubectl get jobs` shows a few, all with 0 completions. But I see 0 pods if I `kubectl get pods`.

Comment: @the0ther since it has 0 completions, could it be that no Pods have actually been run? (They failed to start) If the Pod was started successfully, then the Pod should be retained. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup